# PartialFunction type

Tags: scala

in scala play framework I seen this code:

```
abstract class AnalyserInfo
case class ColumnC(typeName:String,fieldName:String) extends AnalyserInfo
case class TableC(typeName:String) extends AnalyserInfo

    val asIs :PartialFunction[AnalyserInfo,String] = {
      case ColumnC(_,f) => f;
      case TableC(typeName) => typeName
    }
```

What is the difference with:

```
val asIs: (AnaliserInfo)=>String = (info) => info match {
  case ColumnC(_,f) => f;
  case TableC(typeName) => typeName
}
```

There is a preferred style? and why in the first case the match keyword can be omitted?

Thank you for the support.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Double => Double` is just a shorthand for `Function[Double, Double]`. `PartialFunction` inherits from `Function` but adds a few methods. Most importantly, it adds the method `isDefinedAt` which allows you to query if the function is defined for some parameter.

The `case`s without a match are a special syntax to define partial functions, which generates an `isDefinedAt` that returns `true` for all matching `case`s.

Say we have a function that returns 1/x, but only for positive values of x, we could it define as:

```
scala> val f: (Double => Double) = { case x if x > 0 => 1/x }             
f: (Double) => Double = <function1>
```

or as:

```
scala> val g: PartialFunction[Double, Double] = { case x if x > 0 => 1/x }
g: PartialFunction[Double,Double] = <function1>
```

The second version has the benefit that we could check if the function is applicable to some parameter:

```
scala> g.isDefinedAt(-3)
res0: Boolean = false
```

This feature is for example used in Scala to implement the actor library where an Actor might only consume certain types of messages.